# Realm データの値の上書きだけしたい

Tags: swift, xcode, realm

ボタンをタップしたら値が上書きされるようにしたいのですが、上書きした後に新しいデータが生成されてしまいます。

過去の類似投稿を参考にしたのですが、うまくいかず、原因を教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

参考:
[Realmの値を上書きしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/30111/realm%E3%81%AE%E5%80%A4%E3%82%92%E4%B8%8A%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

**ソースコード**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var Button: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let realm = try! Realm()

    let Contents = [Box(value: ["id": 0, "status": 0])]

    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(Contents)
    }

}

@IBAction func tap(_ sender: Any) {

    let realm = try! Realm()
    let call = realm.objects(Box.self)
    try! realm.write() {
        call[0].status = 1;
        print(call)
    }
}
```

Comment: Viewが表示されるたびに値が挿入されるようになっていますので、そこの問題なのでは？

Comment: @masakih １回しか表示されないようにViewを変更したら解決できました！ありがとうございました。